Is there a way to check if a path exists on a network drive?
When I try to check whether a specified path exists in a network drive, it always returns false.
I am trying to call an internal program that creates a backup of a database. In the arguments, I specify the path to be on a network drive (Z:\temp). The program checks whether the given path exists ("Directory.Exists(directory);"). Returns false if the path is on a network drive. I have also tried the new DirectoryInfo(directoy).Exists, but it is also false. Is there a way to check whether a patch exists in a network drive?
I also tried Directory.GetCreationTime(directoy), but it returned '01.01.1601 01:00:00,” so I can’t use it either.
